# How can I access attribute on Angular directive from the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a **starred** directive. On this directive I can set `object-class="customer"`.
How can I access this attribute from the belonging controller? I want to do different things within the controller regarding which value being set as object-class.

**HTML**

```
<starred object-class="martin"></starred>
```

**template**

```
<span class="fa fa-star" ng-click="star_clicked($event)">Star</span>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('starred', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      objectClass: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/templates/starred.html.slim',
    controller: function($scope, $attrs) {
      return $scope.star_clicked = function(e) {
        var id = $(e.target).closest('tr').data('customer-id');
        console.log("info: " + $attrs.objectClass);
        console.log("id: " + id);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Inject $attrs in the controller - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @martin take a look at my answer

Comment: @Sacho, thanks! That solved it! :-) I've updated the code in my post to a working example.